# Chromaticity correction

Tags: python, opencv, png

I have a 48 bit PNG file saved as raw data with Gamma correction and Chromaticty values recorded in the file, as noted by Image Magick:

```
Gamma: 0.45455
Chromaticity:
  red primary: (0.64,0.33)
  green primary: (0.3,0.6)
  blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
  white point: (0.3127,0.326)
```

When loaded up via `cv2.imread()` the sky has a nasty green colour, and even after [doing gamma correction](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/05/opencv-gamma-correction/) a green tinge remains, so I suspect I have to apply the chromaticity values, but I cannot find a decent explanation of how to do this. How would I go about applying these values to a standard `numpy` array?

Comment: Those happen to be the sRGB values so the gAMA and cHRM chunks aren't really doing anything; browsers will assume sRGB anyhow.

Comment: @Glenn, yes, it appears browsers and even Photoshop is ignoring that metadata (or applying it wrongly). I want to find out why the colours are off and what is needed to correct it, and the gAMA and cHRM seemed the best place to start; is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: It's hard to say what happened without seeing your image.  How was the image created in the first place?